# Multiple JSON Path in OutPutPath in AWS Step Function

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I have following JSON as Input to the state:

```
{
  "s3Key": "GermanTest/train/train.txt",
  "s3Bucket": "sukhwant-test-us-east-1",
  "gdsInputFileType": "IOBES",
  "batchSize": 5,
  "count": 1,
  "minimumAttributeLabels": {
    "brand": 1,
    "size": 5
  },
  "gtLabellingJobConfig": {
   "a" : "b"
  }
}
```

I want to output only some fields from this input as step output. Is it possible to do this using Output Path?

Comment: If everything is under one parent node, you can use  `outputpath` in Amazon State Language.